# Articles with "calls" and "stories"?

Tags: articles, definite-articles

I'm responding a test. I write a correct answer:

> - I was telling *the* stories this time yesterday.
> - He isn't answering *the calls* at the moment.

Is the use of the definite article in these examples correct?

Comment: Why do you think you wouldn't be able to? Please [edit](http://english.stackexchange.com/posts/185546/edit) this to help us understand why you think these are questionable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

> I was telling the stories this time yesterday.

I was telling stories at this time yesterday.

would be more correct.

And talking about

> He isn't answering the calls at the moment.

you can remove **the** here.(optional)

You should use **the** when you have to refer to something specific.

Read about where to use **the**, [here](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/)
and where **not** to use **the**, [here.](http://www.englishteachermelanie.com/grammar-when-not-to-use-the-definite-article/)